# How can I improve my question “win32 function not resolved even when header is included”

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes, post-ban

[Win32 Function Not Resolved even when header is included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746672/win32-function-not-resolved-even-when-header-is-included)

I got -2 downvotes on this question even though I had revised it. The question is already solved, but the downvotes are taken into account of my question ban.

This question is because I had misconceptions of the library reference. I mistakenly thought just by including the header I can reference the library. But in fact, i also have to add #comment(“lib”... macros to tell the application what I library I want to include.

But I don’t know how I can revise it to make my expression better. I think it’s not a quality problem for a beginner developer to have some misconceptions at the library reference, and I think it can contribute to the community because many new developers can have the same misconception.

I need some advice of how I can improve this question? And where I am going wrong in asking the question? Is my title unclear? Or something else.

Comment: There really nothing you can do to "improve" question when you did not look for error message before asking... Basically you'd need to say something like "I searched for error code https://www.bing.com/search?q=LNK2019 and it says I need to add library but I don't want to try it"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it is NOT that I don’t want to try. It’s I mistakenly thought the include macro is adding the library. I won’t bother asking if I just kinda “don’t want to try”.

Comment: You can try to put your own text after "I searched for error code" (I just could not come up with any sensible example here). The problem is at least Google and Bing bring MSDN article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=vs-2019) as first result that directly links to answer that is currently selected as duplicate. You can try to "edit to show that linked question does not answer the question" (which is what you need in case of duplicate)… but that's insanely hard in this case.

Comment: Since this is tagged [[meta-tag:post-ban]], and you are indeed [currently blocked from asking questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583), here's a list of your deleted questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59153975), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59098917), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59070582), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58473651), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58351600).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tooltip on the downvote arrow reads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

This provides a clue to understanding the downvotes on your question. In particular, the first phrase there, the one about "does not show any research effort".

Having simply searched for the error message; either:

> unresolved external symbol

or

> LNK2019

you would have ended up either on [the official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019) or [this MSDN FAQ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a7b43de-60ed-4274-8a67-349a2a34da7a/faq-28-why-would-one-get-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol?forum=vcgeneral) or a veritable cornucopia of Stack Overflow questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769977/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error-in-visual-studio-c) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

Any or all of these would have given you your answer. Especially that last Stack Overflow question, of which your question was closed as a duplicate.

Alternatively, you could have looked up the name of the function which you were trying to call (`ImageList_Create`), which would have almost certainly gotten you to [the official MSDN documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_create). Like all functions documented on MSDN, there is a table at the bottom, titled "Requirements", which summarizes the versions of Windows on which the function is available, the header file you need to include, and the library or DLL that you need to reference in order to call the function.

Combined with the knowledge that LNK2019 is a linker error indicating that the linker could not find an external symbol (i.e., the function that you were trying to call), you could have easily pieced together the solution to your problem: add a reference to `Comctl32.lib` to your project's build settings so that the linker could find the `ImageList_Create` function, which it exports.

In other words: you should have been able to find the answer to this question yourself, with a minimal amount of research effort. As such, at least two users found your question to be worthy of a downvote.

To be clear, that does not necessarily mean that you should not have asked the question. If you *genuinely* couldn't find the answer, even after doing some research, then it is fair to ask the question. You did—after all—get your answer. However, it is *also* fair to expect some downvotes, since other Stack Overflow users will likely consider the question to be exhibiting a lack of research effort and thus not useful to others in the future.

There is another [related] problem, as is clear from reading the comments: you were operating with an insufficient understanding the C++ build process—namely, that simply including the headers is sufficient. This is not true. Like C, C++ programs are built in multiple steps. Simplifying slightly, first the code file is run through the preprocessor (inserting headers as necessary), then the code file is compiled into an object file, and finally the object file is linked. In order to link, the linker needs to be able to find all externally referenced functions. Not knowing this perhaps made it harder for you to find the answer yourself. But your inability to explain what you did not know (the fact that you lacked a minimal understanding of the language/environment that you were using) also made it difficult for others to understand your question. The question being "unclear" is another common reason for downvotes. Like it or not, Stack Overflow simply isn't an effective resource for programmers who lack a minimal understanding of their language/environment, and questions that demonstrate such lack of knowledge are likely to be unclear to others and thus receive downvotes.