# Question ban lift acting up - should have been lifted

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

About 7 months ago I was question banned - I understand the reasons, for the questions I asked were unclear and... Well I see why anyway. I've also since increased nearly 500 rep since, through good answers and review queues. Just under a week ago, the 6 month one-question ban lift occurred. I used it to ask a question I'd been working out.

Q is [PyCryptoDome/cryptography inequality with AES-CFB in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59712935/10475068)

Now the doc page on this says that if the Q was well received, then the ban would be lifted. The question received upvotes and was, to the best of my understanding well received. Therefore the ban should have been lifted, and me allowed to ask more questions.

For some reason **it wasn't**. Could someone tell me what is going on? The system *appears* to be ignoring the docs.

Comment: Sorry, nowhere is it said that a single good question will lift the ban. The ban is based on your *overall standing*. The 6-monthly 1-question lifting of the question-ban is meant to help you produce a better standing and your last question *helped* but there are no guarantees.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks... Could you have a look at the questions that got my into this? They are the only ones with downvotes of course - I don't know how to improve half of them. I was a bit of an idiot in how I wrote them.

Answer (score 4):

[It says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans):

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you **may** be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

The emphasis has been added, but the Help Center is not providing you with any guarantee.

If you have a history of low-quality contributions, then your overall quality score will be low enough that a single positively-scored question will not be enough to dig you out of the question ban.

To dig yourself out of the ban, [we advise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> **Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, downvotes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Formatted or titled poorly? Too long or too short? **Then fix them!**

Furthermore, since deleted questions still contribute to your overall quality metric, it's worth noting that you have three deleted questions on Stack Overflow:

- [How to read a file as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203135/how-to-read-a-file-as-binary)
- [How to load images from system32.dll in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226792/how-to-load-images-from-system32-dll-in-python)
- [How to use matplotlib to plot how long a task will take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551920/how-to-use-matplotlib-to-plot-how-long-a-task-will-take)

Regardless of how deep you are into the hole (*i.e.*, how low your overall quality score is), though, you will still get the opportunity to as a new question every six months. It is more accurately a "rate limit", rather than an outright ban.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is that I can't fix my previous questions easily... They were asked from me when I was at the stage I thought I new everything and... I'm not like that now. Read my Qs if you want - any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Not being a Python expert, there may not be much I can do to help you directly improve your questions. And, as a moderator, there's nothing I can do with respect to question bans/throttles. They're all implemented algorithmically, with moderators having no control or even really any visibility into the process. I don't, for example, even see how low your total quality score is. I have to just guess, based on how many downvoted questions you have.

Comment: It is possible to ask here on Meta for help improving a *specific* question, but you should do so knowing that attracting that attention to your question may attract even more downvotes, so it is a gamble.

Comment: There is one specific one I'd like to ask about if you could - it's my most downvoted, but also most viewed and arguably best question. Would you mind? It's about bit size maximums...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one. I personally think it's a pretty low-quality question. The problem is not formatting, but runs deeper than that. This is probably something you'd need a Python expert to really help you with improving. To me, it looks like it both lacks a minimal understanding of the topic domain *and* lacks any evidence of research effort (two things that do tend to go hand-in-hand). As to how to fix it, I'm not sure what to recommend. My suggestion was to ask a new question on Meta. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392022) could be used as a model of how to go about doing so.

Comment: Seems it may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818535/how-can-i-set-all-bits-to-1-in-a-binary-number-of-an-unknown-size or other similar questions, since it isn't actually related to Python, as far as I can tell, but just bit-manipulation, or even a fundamental understanding of how numbers are stored inside of binary computers.

Comment: Kinda - it's about how to a specific operation with python. I understand that point of view, but have to point out that there are many other questions that do that. Some of them have upvotes in the thousands.

Comment: It's probably a duplicate of one of those then. How a question is received is a function of when it's asked. If you you're the first person to ask a basic question that's a lot different to being the ten-thousandth person to ask that same question. Highly upvoted basic questions tend to be either a) old (which is why they were first) or b) about a new technology (also why they were first).

Comment: @Legorooj your score is around [0.2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions?negdel=2&closedel=0&deleted=3&UserId=10475068), you need 0.5 to be out of the quality-ban.

Comment: @RobertLongson thx for the feedback and I checked all of those questions and they don't really answer mine.